# Conditional behavior in TestCleanUp if test had failed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-test-runner, test-class

I have a `TestClass`. In my `TestCleanUp` function, I want to do conditional actions depending on wether the test had failed.

I could of course wrap each test with `try`-`catch` and add a flag which I can later query, but I was wondering if there is something built-in to the testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.currenttestoutcome.aspx) contains this information.  You can gain access to the current `TestContext` instance by adding a `TestContext` property to your test class.  e.g.:

```
[TestClass]
public class YourTestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    //...
}
```